# Passing Item ID to JS Function

Tags: javascript, c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework.

Currently I have table with buttons on side:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Name", "DisplayAllAdmin", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "sortLabel" })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Download", "Sth", new { id = item.Id }, null)"><i class="material-icons">get_app</i></a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Sth", new { id = item.Id }, null)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

How to add next button to show record details?

Now I have sth like this:

```
        <tr style="display:none">
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TbVersion)</td>
        </tr>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function DisplayDetails(id) 
        {

            if (document.getElementById("detailsField").style.display == "none")
            {
                document.getElementById("detailsField").style.display = "block";
            }

            else
            {
                document.getElementById("detailsField").style.display = "none"
            }
        }
    </script>

<button onclick="DisplayDetails(id)"><i class="material-icons">info</i></button>
```

But I have troubles with passing the ID. Any suggestions? Thanks very much.

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: Check out bootstrap Collapse. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/ . This will allow you to hide/show records on a click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the parameter like this

```
        <a href="@Url.Action('Delete', 'Sth', new { id = " + item.Id +  "}, null)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
```

Comment: But I dont wanna to Redirect to another Action. I just want the details slide down under selected record.

Comment: I thought your problem was passing the id?